# Laravel 5.7 - Unable to run php artisan commands when shifted project to live

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, clear-cache

I'm new to laravel, My commands of `PHP artisan` were working fine in `localhost`.
When i shifted my project to live server the commands stopped working and gives me following error:

> Warning: require(): Invalid date.timezone value 'GST', we selected the
>   timezone 'UTC' for now. (I fixed this by defining my timezone) Parse
>   error: syntax error, unexpected '?'
>   laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 500

There are actually no errors the project is working fine,My PHP version is `7.2.10`.
I'm inside the directory where PHP artisan is installed but of no use.
I hope I have to clear the cache but how can I clear cache when my artisan commands are not working?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> try to change version in apache

find total install version in server

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

then select one version then check php version again.

```
sudo php -v
```

> second way u can do by this command

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6   //disable old version 
sudo a2enmod php7.2    //enable new version
```

and restart apache2 server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and check php version

```
sudo php -v
```

for more better understanding [see](https://tecadmin.net/switch-between-multiple-php-version-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: My server restricts me I can't run sudo commands but I'll check for sure

Comment: OK I ran the command my php version shows PHP 5.6.38 but I can't still run php artisan command.

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --config php  and sudo php -v then run php artisan server . It didn't work for me

Comment: PHP 5.6.38 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Oct  5 2018 15:45:28)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group with php -v command

Comment: @SaniaIshaq  join this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182923/versionissue

Comment: I can't, I should have 20+ reputation to join the room

Comment: @SaniaIshaq try to install php 7.1 version and set as default version ..

Comment: So i downgraded my php to version 7.1 updated the system to it. I got some exceptions but it worked.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

did you install composer and packages? with `composer install` command on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform below steps.

**1) First you have to check the apache is starting or not.**

**2) Then you have to Install the composer and command like (i.e.
    composer update)**

**3) You have to clear cache and command like below**

1) php artisan config:cache
   2) php artisan view:clear

Comment: Composer is installed and updated but my php artisan commands gives error

Comment: @Sania Ishaq Can you check with PHP Version 7.1 or 7.0 something?

Comment: I updated to PHP Version 7.2.10  before shifting project.

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded the PHP version to 7.1 and upgraded the system to same php version.
Got some exceptions later but it resolves the issue.